# Why is memcache not functioning with elgg in debian 7?

Tags: nginx, php5, memcached, memcache

I am moving a php website (built using elgg - www.elgg.org) from a CentOS server to a different Debian 7 server and have installed memcached + php5-memcache on both.

I have recreated all the necessary setup steps that I am aware of on the Debian 7 machine to activate memcache and get the php site to use it - however, when I view the site, I see the following in the logs:

```
PHP WARNING: "Memcache::getversion(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" in file /mysite/ElggMemcache.php (line 88)
PHP message: "Memcache::getversion(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" in file /mysite/engine/classes/ElggMemcache.php (line 88)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mysite.com
```

From what I can tell (and based on reading other related threads online) - the php code is not able to connect to the memcache server process. The php app and the memcache server process are on the same server and I have looked in the hosts file to ensure that `localhost` is listed against `127.0.0.1`.

Changing the `localhost` reference within the elgg code to `127.0.0.1` didn't make any difference.

I am out of ideas now. Does anyone know what I could have missed?

Comment: did you actually check line 88 of the following file? `/mysite/ElggMemcache.php (line 88)` If so what does it say?

Comment: Also which release of elgg are you using? 1.8.18 or 1.7.21?

Comment: i am using elgg 1.8.18 here.
line 88 of the file is the attempt to access the version of the current memcache server within the elgg memcache class:

$this->version = $this->memcache->getVersion();